# BasicAuth with ServiceStack 4.05

Tags: authorization, servicestack

I'm following an online course on ServiceStack. Most of the example code is 3.x based but gets easily converted to 4.05. However the authorization gives me a problem I can not solve, I configure the authentication in the global.asax.cs as follows:

```
    public class ProteinTrackerAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public ProteinTrackerAppHost() : base("Protein Tracker",typeof(EntryService).Assembly) {}

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }));

           container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
           var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
           container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);

           string hash;
           string salt;

           new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("bhuijn", out hash, out salt);
           userRepository.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
               {
                   Id = 1,
                   DisplayName = "JoeUser",
                   Email = "joe@user.com",
                   UserName = "martin",
                   FirstName = "joe",
                   LastName = "User",
                   PasswordHash = hash,
                   Salt = salt
               }, "bhuijn");

        }
```

this compiles and runs ok, I then connect from a client using this code:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:49172/") 
             { UserName = "martin", Password = "bhuijn" };
```

each service that gets called works ok except for those that have authentication required like

```
[Route("/status")]
[Authenticate]
public class StatusQuery : IReturn<StatusResponse>
{
```

Which give me an exception "Not Found".

Any ideas appreciated

Stack trace:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'ServiceStack.WebServiceException' occurred in
ServiceStack.Client.dll
Not Found
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowWebServiceException[TResponse](Exception ex,
    String requestUri)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowResponseTypeException[TResponse](Object request,
   Exception ex, String requestUri)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.HandleResponseException[TResponse](Exception ex,
   Object request, String requestUri, Func`1 createWebRequest, Func`2 getResponse,
   TResponse& response)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String
   relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Post[TResponse](String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object
   requestDto)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Post[TResponse](IReturn`1 requestDto)
at Consumer.Program.Main(String[] args) in
   c:\projects\servicestack1\Consumer\Program.cs:line 29
```

the responseBody was:

```
Handler for Request not found: 
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: /login.aspx
Request.QueryString: ReturnUrl=%2fstatus
Request.RawUrl: /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fstatus
```

basically the web.conf looks like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <!-- preCondition="IntegratedMode" -->
  <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: Can you edit and include the stack trace in your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Your response-body information is indicating that you are being redirected to a "login.aspx" page, which likely doesn't exist? Therefore, it can't find your login page and is giving you a not-found error. This leads me to assume that you have forms-authentication configured in your web.config? Look for that setting and comment out the forms-authentication.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I had no authentication configured and IIS defaulted to Forms authentication. After adding   <authentication mode="None" /> everything works as it was supposed to do.